# MouseOver CSS3D effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I am trying to achieve mouseOver effect like this.

[image]

I am able to generate css3d matrix required for each and every tile according to their position.

I have achieved this effect with slow mouse movement, but if I am moving fast from one tile to another tile its notupdating properly. its showing gap in between tiles. What is the best way to update all the tile/tile co-ordinates on mouseover so that i get consistent effect?

here is my js code:

```
 $('.box').each(function() {
            $(this).css('height', '284px');
            $(this).css('width', '284px');
        });

        generateGrid = function(w, h) {
            var t = this;
            this.p = [];
            var d = 30;


            var c = Math.floor($('.w').outerWidth() / 284 + 1);
            var r = Math.ceil($('.w').outerHeight() / 284) + 1;
            var vc = c * r;
            for (i = 0; i < vc; i++) {
                var l = {
                    x: Math.floor(i % c) * 284,
                    y: Math.floor(i / c) * 284
                };
                this.p.push(l);
            }
            var m = m || {};

            m.Grid = function() {
                this.elms = [];
                this.init();
            }, m.Grid.prototype = {
                init: function() {
                    this.createTiles();
                },
                animateTile: function() {
                    var e = this;
                    for (i = 0; i < e.elms.length; i++) {
                        console.log(i);
                        e.elms[i].update();
                    }
                    requestAnimationFrame($.proxy(this.animateTile, this));
                },
                createTiles: function() {
                    var c = this;
                    for (i = 0; i < $('.box').length; i++) {
                        c.elms.push(new m.tile($('.box:eq(' + i + ')'), i));
                    }

                    c.animateTile();
                }
            }, m.tile = function(e, i, pt) {
                this.el = e;
                this.i = i;
                var p = t.p;
                this.elX = Math.floor(i % 4) * 284,
                        this.elY = Math.floor(i / 4) * 284,
                        this.p1 = p[i + Math.floor(i / 4)],
                        this.p2 = p[i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 1],
                        this.p3 = p[i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 6]
                this.p4 = p[i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 5];


                this.init();
            }, m.tile.prototype = {
                init: function() {

                    this.initEvents();
                },
                initEvents: function() {
                    var e = this;
                    var pts = t.p;
                    var p1 = pts[e.i + Math.floor(i / 4)],
                            p2 = pts[e.i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 1],
                            p3 = pts[e.i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 6],
                            p4 = pts[e.i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 5];


                    $(e.el).hover(function() {
                        TweenMax.killTweensOf(p1),
                                TweenMax.killTweensOf(p2),
                                TweenMax.killTweensOf(p3),
                                TweenMax.killTweensOf(p4),
                                TweenMax.to(p1, .3, {
                            x: p1.x - d,
                            y: p1.y - d,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        }),
                        TweenMax.to(p2, .3, {
                            x: p2.x + d,
                            y: p2.y - d,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        }),
                        TweenMax.to(p3, .3, {
                            x: p3.x + d,
                            y: p3.y + d,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        }),
                        TweenMax.to(p4, .3, {
                            x: p4.x - d,
                            y: p4.y + d,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        }),
                        TweenMax.to(e.el, .3, {
                            zIndex: 10,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        });

                    }, function() {
                        TweenMax.killTweensOf(p1),
                                TweenMax.killTweensOf(p2),
                                TweenMax.killTweensOf(p3),
                                TweenMax.killTweensOf(p4);

                        TweenMax.to(p1, .7, {
                            x: p1.x + d,
                            y: p1.y + d,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        }),
                        TweenMax.to(p2, .7, {
                            x: p2.x - d,
                            y: p2.y + d,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        }),
                        TweenMax.to(p3, .7, {
                            x: p3.x - d,
                            y: p3.y - d,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        }),
                        TweenMax.to(p4, .7, {
                            x: p4.x + d,
                            y: p4.y - d,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        }),
                        TweenMax.to(e.el, .7, {
                            zIndex: 0,
                            ease: Back.easeOut
                        });
                    });
                },
                update: function() {
                    var e = this;
                    var pts = t.p;
                    var p1 = pts[e.i + Math.floor(i / 4)],
                            p2 = pts[e.i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 1],
                            p3 = pts[e.i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 6],
                            p4 = pts[e.i + Math.floor(i / 4) + 5];
                    BLEND.TransformElement(
                            {
                                el: e.el[0],
                                src: [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: w, y: 0}, {x: w, y: h}, {x: 0, y: h}],
                                dest: [
                                    {x: p1.x - e.elX,
                                        y: p1.y - e.elY},
                                    {x: p2.x - e.elX,
                                        y: p2.y - e.elY},
                                    {x: p3.x - e.elX,
                                        y: p3.y - e.elY},
                                    {x: p4.x - e.elX,
                                        y: p4.y - e.elY},
                                ]
                            });
                }
            };

            t.grid = new m.Grid();
        };
        generateGrid(284, 284);
```

BLEND.TransformElement(el,src,dest) in my code gives CSS3D matrix, it's working fine. I need to update vertices properly.

Here is my html and CSS:

```
<style>
       .box{
            float: left;
            background: #2b5349;
            transform-origin: 0px 0px;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="w" style=" margin-bottom:190px;display:inline-block;width: calc(284px * 4); margin:100px auto;">
        <div class="box" style="background: red"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: #2b5349"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: green"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: blue"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: darkgoldenrod"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: fuchsia"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: lightpink"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: mediumspringgreen"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: burlywood"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: orange"></div>
        <div class="box" style="background: gold"></div>
        <div class="box" ></div>
    </div>
```

I am doing all this this from start without using any external plugin for that particular effect. Please suggest some solution.

I have stored all the vertices of all tiles and updating it on mouseover. as soon as I mouseover from one tile to another animation for resetting vertices values from new one to original stops. How can I fix vertices update problem on mouseenter and mouseleave envent.

Comment: I have edited the question to specify problem. I am using js code above to update tiles but there is some problem for which I need help.

Comment: Your "working demo" is not working at all (404 Not Found).

Comment: @Dramorian If possible create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)  with your code

Comment: @Aminul yeah sure. I'll in next few days ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Solved the problem. Problem was with not updating vertices value to the original on mouseout event. to revert vertices value to original question i have to keep extra value of vertices like this.

```
var l = {
                x: Math.floor(i % c) * 284,
                y: Math.floor(i / c) * 284,
                x2: Math.floor(i % c) * 284,
                y2: Math.floor(i / c) * 284,

            };
```

On mouseover change the vertice value like this for every coordinate

```
 TweenMax.to(p1, .3, {
                        x: p1.x2 + d,
                        y: p1.y2 - d,
                        ease: Back.easeOut
                    })
```

and on mouseout reset original position

```
 TweenMax.to(p2, .3, {
                        x: p2.x,
                        y: p2.y,
                        ease: Back.easeOut
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this working for a flexible number of columns. Currently it only seems to work for 4!

Comment: could you please provide the details on what needs to be tweaked? Thank you!

Comment: You can use plugin from gitHub http://rawgit.com/Manish2612/Inflate/master/inflate.html